# Installation of linux-image package fails

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, software-installation, upgrade

I get an issue installing Let's Encrypt.

Command : `sudo ./certbot-auto`

Issue :

```
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic (3.16.0-70.90~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic_3.16.0-70.90~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
« ./boot/System.map-3.16.0-70-generic » to « /boot/System.map-3.16.0-70-generic.dpkg-new » : No space left on device
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-70-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-70-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-70-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-70-generic
dpkg-deb : (Broken pipe)
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-77-generic_3.16.0-77.99~14.04.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-70-generic_3.16.0-70.90~14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with Let's Encrypt or `certbot`, and has everything to do with space exhaustion on `/boot`.

Answer (score 0):

Free up space. If you run `df -h` you'll likely see 100%